# How do import statements get resolved in multiple source files?

Tags: go, package

I've been trying to find an answer to this question without success.

The question is about import statements in Go when a package consists of multiple source files.

Let's say I have a package called `math` which consists of multiple files:

```
|-- math
   |-- add.go
   |-- subtract.go
   |-- divide.go
   |-- multiply.go
```

Let's assume that the `math` package makes use of the `fmt` package therefore it needs the appropriate import statement. But since we have four separate files, we have to import the `fmt` package multiple times (at least to my understanding):

```
// add.go
import "fmt"

// subtract.go
import "fmt"

// divide.go
import "fmt"

// multiply.go
import "fmt"
```

Now the question is, what happens when the package is compiled? Are the statements simply merged together?

If so, why do we have to import the package multiple times (once per each file) and not just have a single file with all the import statements so as to not repeat ourselves?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [specification says](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope):

> The scope of the package name of an imported package is the file block of the file containing the import declaration.

Because imports do not have package scope, imports are not merged together and are required in each file that uses the import.

The scoping for imports is unrelated to how the compiler and linker load imported packages. These tools are smart enough to load any given package once.

Comment: So when I import the `fmt` package four times, how does the compiler make sure that it's not linking the package four times in the same build? I would assume that since the import statement has only 'file scope' the compiler has to somehow combine all the imported libraries to avoid linking the same one twice.

Comment: The compiler only builds any package once. If you want to know *how* it does so, read the compile source code, it's [open source and available on GitHub](https://github.com/golang/go).

Comment: @Rtsne42 The scope of identifiers is unrelated to how the compiler and linker load packages.  These tools are smart enough to load any given package once.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Thanks, I'm sure they load the package only once. I was just wondering how it does that when there are duplicate import statements across multiple files. That said, your answer did clarify things for me.